# Pandas is too slow while importing data form World Bank using pandas datareader

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-datareader

I have a problem with pandas datareader.
I want to import data from World Bank, but it lasts to long and shows error.

The code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas_datareader import wb
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import datetime
ind = ['SI.DST.10TH.10',
       'SI.DST.05TH.20',
       'SI.DST.FRST.10',
       'SI.DST.FRST.20',
       'SI.POV.GINI']
df = wb.download(indicator=ind, country='SRB', start=2000, end=2022).dropna();df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.columns = ['Country',
              'Year',
              'Income share - highest 10%',
              'Income share - highest 20%',
              'Income share - lowest 10%',
              'Income share - lowest 10%',
              'GINI Index']
df=df.sort_values(by='Year', ascending=True)
df.head()
```

The error is as follows:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='fred.stlouisfed.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=30)
```

How can i solve this?
Thnak you.

Comment: The request is timing out. It doesn't look like there's much you can do about this as the `wb.download()` method is missing the `timeout` parameter present in many of the other functions. You could just try again later and see if it's a problem on the server side? The `pandas-datareader` library doesn't look like it's getting much maintenance.

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis it fixed itself. I just restart the workspace :) thank you bro